# Capture JSON property names with regex

Tags: regex, typescript

I want to create a regex that will capture property names in JSON objects. So I can color their property names. Then, in loop (in TypeScript), I will add a span with class to color captured matches.

For example:

I have an object that looks like this

```
{"restriction_data" : "ALL","old" : null,"new" : ["ALL"],"record_type" : "product"}
```

I want to get *restriction_data*, *old*, *new*, *record_type* from regex and make it red in color.

Other JSON that I can get is:

```
{"category":"category is mandatory","field":"[u'NONE'] is invalid field. Found: NONE","description":"description is mandatory"}
```

And same, I want to get *category*, *field*, *description* and make it red.

I tried `\"(.*?)\"` regex, but it doesn't quite work for me.

Comment: Try this `(?<=,|{)".+?"\s?(?=:)`

Comment: what about `"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"(?=\s*:)` or just `"[^"\\]*"(?=\s*:)` if property can't contain backslash

Comment: Use a JSON parser to convert it to an object or array and iterate through the keys.

Comment: ^Indeed, using a JSON parser is the best way. No matter how accurate you try to make your regex, it can't catch all edge cases you can have with nested quotes, escaped quotes, etc.